# I sent PRL token to contract address instead of wallet address

Tags: blockchain, ether, wallets, tokens, myetherwallet

I am wondering if i can recover the tokens. I sent PRL tokens to contract address  0x1844b21593262668B7248d0f57a220CaaBA46ab9 instead of myetherwallet address from kucoin exchange wallet. :-( 
Are they lost forever ?
I feel like an idiot and it would be so kind if someone could tell me if something can be done to get my Oyster Pearl token back.
However, happy new year everyone !

Comment: It appears you are out of luck, I didn't see in their contract a way to recover unintentional transfered tokens. You should ask the team in any case to be sure.

Comment: thank  you for answering me. I can't figure out a way to reach the contract team

Comment: i can't find any info about them. Too Bad.

Comment: They have a webpage https://oyster.ws/, and they list a Twitter account and other social media hubs.

Comment: Bad luck! Hope you recover your coins. I want to transfer PRL from Kucoin to Myetherwallet, which way is the safe one?
Anyone could success at doing that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

sadly my tokens are lost forever. you have to add the token manually. the contract address to add is the one in my first post, decimal is 18 and PRL for the token. But verify with Ethplorer.io Then send them to your wallet address. it's not hard but triple check the address you paste un kucoin. it must be your main wallet address. not the contract address.